# Mono:Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow'

Tags: c#, ubuntu, msbuild, mono, roslyn

We are using **C# Roslyn Version 2.3.1** for opening **.csproj** projects programmatically.

For this purpose, we are using the following standard API code provided by Roslyn for opening the .csproj and navigating through each **Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Document** to get the syntax tree of the Document:

```
public void BrowsProjectDocuments(string projectPath)
{
   var workspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
   workspace.WorkspaceFailed += WorkSpaceFailed;
   Project currentProject = workspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectPath).Result;    

   foreach(Document document in currentProject.Documents)
   {
        Task<SyntaxTree>  documentSyntaxTree = document.GetSyntaxTreeAsync();
        .....
        .....
   } 
}

private static void WorkSpaceFailed(object sender, WorkspaceDiagnosticEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Diagnostic.Message);
}
```

When we run the above code on **Windows 7** using **.NET Framework 4.6.1/4.6.2** and **Roslyn 2.3.1**, the code runs well and **we get the required syntax tree of each Document**.

But when we try to run the same code on **Ubuntu 16.04**, **currentProject.Documents** returns **0** count and we get following error thrown in the **WorkSpaceFailed** event hooked up:

> Msbuild failed when processing the file
>   '/home/user/CSharp/RoslynSamples/AplModel/AplModel.csproj'
>   with message: 
>   Could not load type of field
>   'Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.LoggingService:_loggingQueue' (20)
>   due to: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.24.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>   assembly:System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.5.24.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a type: member:

We have installed mono on the Ubuntu machine using:

> sudo apt-get install mono-complete

What are we missing?

Answer (score 1):

Look a workaround here: https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1469
You need to use a Mono hosted MSBuild (for example, taken from Mono or built under Mono), install System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow and Microsoft.VisualStudio.RemoteControl packages from NuGet.

Answer (score 0):

The MSBuildWorkspace is not currently cross platform. It only works on .net desktop clr.  But my knowledge of mono is not so good, so it may be possible to get it to work on mono.  Your error message tells me that you need to include the DataFlow library somehow.